# How to add progressive 'count' in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I format cells such that when entering data, formatting automagically add a number before the text such that the number is equal to a number+1 from a an adjacent cell (in my case from above)

[image]

Comment: there will be no gaps but counting would start not absolutely from 1st row in sheet, may start in row 39 then continue downwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could use the [ROW()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/row-function-HP010342861.aspx) function instead of a hidden column

If your table starts on row 8, column B, then in cell C8 have

```
=CONCATENATE(ROW(B8)-7," ",B8)
```

The 7 is 1 less than the row number of the starting row, and stays the same all the way down.

[image]

Don't forget the space between the number and the word with the ," ", in the middle of the concatenate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a (hidden if required) column that contains the numbers, and at the last column use Concatenate like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack

It assumes you won't be using Row 1 (if you do, you'll have to add different code for that row or manually enter the value.

It also assumes there will be no gaps in your lists.

This also only goes up to 99!

```
=IF(A5="","",CONCATENATE(IF(C4<>"",LEFT(C4,2)+1,"1")," " & A5))
```

[image]

In Row C1 I manually typed in the 0 just to show it's not in use.